# Spreading values on data.tables

Tags: r, data.table, spread

I'm new to R and I would like to know if there is a library for spreading and by  spreading I mean that for example if I have this data.table:

```
DT <- data.table(V1 = c(1L,2L), V2 = LETTERS[1:4], V4 = 1:4)
```

and I assing 15 to the `V4` column:

```
DT$V4 = 15
```

the values will be adjusted so that the sum is now 15:

```
DT <- data.table(V1 = c(1L,2L), V2 = LETTERS[1:4], V4 = c(1.5,3,4.5,6)).
```

(The new values result from being multiplied by 15/sum(column) --> 15 / 10)

This is the easiest example of what I have to do, that's why I ask if there is a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below to calculate the number to be multiplied `15/10=1.5` and then multiply it by `.I`

```
DT <- data.table(V1 = c(1L,2L), V2 = LETTERS[1:4], V4 = 1:4)
DT$V4 = 15
DT[,V4:=.I*V4/sum(seq(.N))]

DT
# V1 V2  V4
# 1:  1  A 1.5
# 2:  2  B 3.0
# 3:  1  C 4.5
# 4:  2  D 6.0
```